# C # ListBox how to export a file with the name I pass from the listbox

Tags: c#, listbox

**sorry for my english but i don't know very well in google translate i do translation.

I want from my listbox the file that I choose to be exported with the same name that it has in my listbox**

```
       private void downloadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string ip = txt_ip.Text;
        string user = txt_user.Text;
        string pass = txt_pass.Text;
        //string pathLocalFile = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "download_sftp_file.txt");
        try
        {
            SftpClient client = new SftpClient(ip, user, pass);
            client.Connect();

            string rmDer = dr_finder.Text;

            var files = client.ListDirectory(rmDer);


            if (rmDer == "")
            {
                client.Connect();

                string rmDerNow = "/";

                var filesName = client.ListDirectory(rmDerNow);

                foreach (var file in filesName)
                {
                    DirList.Items.Add(file.Name);
                    string result = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.Name);
                    DirList.Items.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.Name));
                }
                MessageBox.Show("List Directory Success!");
            }

            string pachRemFile = DirList.SelectedItem.ToString();
            string pachlocalFile = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop),"Server Ftp File.txt");

            Stream Filestream = File.OpenWrite(pachlocalFile);
            client.DownloadFile(pachRemFile,Filestream);
            client.Disconnect();
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(error.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

this object is the solution I finally didn't find anyone to help me. so I helped myself.
and I thought he had good programmers on this site

```
 SaveFileDialog savefile = new SaveFileDialog(); /* this here is my solution get a save as. */

            if (savefile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)   
            {
                string pachRemFile = DirList.SelectedItem.ToString();
                Stream Filestream = File.Open(savefile.FileName, FileMode.CreateNew);
                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Filestream);
                client.DownloadFile(pachRemFile, Filestream);
                client.Disconnect();
            }
```

Comment: Glad you found an answer. All people on StackOverflow are volunteers and often they can help. In this case, I did not understand your question, and maybe others also did not understand it. Sorry to hear you feel left alone here. This not the general intention.

Comment: I agree with what you say and I expected it I don't know cities well english financial for help google translate.at least to change the title and put: how to make C# save as a file or export file